# How can I detect the operating system in Perl?

Tags: perl, cross-platform

I have Perl on Mac, Windows and Ubuntu. How can I tell from within the script which one is which?

**Edit:** I was asked what I am doing. It is a script, part of our cross-platform build system. The script recurses directories and figures out what files to build. Some files are platform-specific, and thus, on Linux I don't want to build the files ending with _win.cpp, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to know? [There may be a more appropriate answer to your question, depending on what (if anything) it is you're doing that's platform-dependant.]

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Examine the [`$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME) variable which will contain the name of the operating system:

```
print "$^O\n";
```

Which prints `linux` on Linux and `MSWin32` on Windows.

You can also refer to this variable by the name [`$OSNAME`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME) if you use the [English](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html) module:

```
use English qw' -no_match_vars ';
print "$OSNAME\n";
```

According to [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html), [`$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME) will be `darwin` on Mac OS X.

---

You can also use the [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) core module, which can provide the same information (and a lot more):

```
use Config;

print "$Config{osname}\n";
print "$Config{archname}\n";
```

Which on my Ubuntu machine prints:

```
linux
i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Note that this information is based on the system that Perl was *built*, which is not necessarily the system Perl is currently running on (the same is true for [`$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME) and [`$OSNAME`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME)); the OS won't likely be different but some information, like the architecture name, may very well be.

Comment: Thanks :) And for other people who may use this answer, cygwin perl returns "cygwin", so there are two possibilities for Windows.

Comment: More than two; there's was a dos port, and the os2 port used to be able to run on windows.  All possible values of $^O are in theory documented in <http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html>.

Comment: print "$^O\n"; does indeed print "darwin" on my Mac OS X sysem.

Comment: @ysth typo in your link by the way

Comment: The typo comes from the trailing angle bracket. It should be [perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html).

Comment: Works even for Windows 10's Windows Subsystem for Linux: stating "linux" when executed via ubuntu-bash, "msys" and in _native_ Windows mode.

Comment: In case anyone gets temporarily stuck on this because you're getting `STDOUT_TOP0` as the output, make sure you're using `$^O` instead of `$^0`. I can't tell you how I know this, but trust me...

Answer (score 15):

If you need more specific information on Windows this may help.

```
my $osname = $^O;


if( $osname eq 'MSWin32' ){{
  eval { require Win32; } or last;
  $osname = Win32::GetOSName();

  # work around for historical reasons
  $osname = 'WinXP' if $osname =~ /^WinXP/;
}}
```

*Derived from [sysinfo.t](https://github.com/parrot/parrot/blob/master/t/dynoplibs/sysinfo.t), which I wrote the original version.*

If you need more detailed information:

```
my ( $osvername, $major, $minor, $id ) = Win32::GetOSVersion();
```

Comment: win32 uses a deprecated function GetVersionExA. This does not work vor Version > 6.2

Comment: @MayraDelgado Indeed, and it looks like there is no direct replacement. Which is why someone who needs this should figure out how to fix it and provide a pull request. I rarely use Windows anymore anyway, so it isn't likely to be me.

Answer (score 11):

Look inside the source for [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec) to see how it loads the right delegate based on the operating system. :)

`File::Spec` has a separate Perl module file for each OS. `File::Spec::Win32`, `File::Spec::OS2`, etc...

It checks the operating system and will load the appropriate `.pm` file at runtime based on OS.

```
# From the source code of File::Spec
my %module = (
      MSWin32 => 'Win32',
      os2     => 'OS2',
      VMS     => 'VMS',
      NetWare => 'Win32', # Yes, File::Spec::Win32 works on NetWare.
      symbian => 'Win32', # Yes, File::Spec::Win32 works on symbian.
      dos     => 'OS2',   # Yes, File::Spec::OS2 works on DJGPP.
      cygwin  => 'Cygwin',
      amigaos => 'AmigaOS');


my $module = $module{$^O} || 'Unix';

require "File/Spec/$module.pm";
our @ISA = ("File::Spec::$module");
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer out of all of these. Unfortunately it's not voted as popular because no one wants to do any research on their own beyond Stack Overflow. I am going to add to the answer so lazy people don't have to go through all of the hard work of clicking on a link. :P

Answer (score 8):

[Sys::Info::OS](http://p3rl.org/Sys::Info::OS) looks like a relatively clean potential solution, but currently doesn't seem to support Mac. It shouldn't be too much work to add that though.

Comment: This would have been a better answer, if only it would support Mac. I prefer the compiler-aided functions, to the maintenance-problem strings.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](http://www.rocketaware.com/perl/perlfaq8/How_do_I_find_out_which_operatin.htm) a quick reference on how to find the OS the local machine is running from Perl.

> The $^O variable ($OSTYPE if you use English) contains the operating system that your perl binary was built for.

Answer (score 4):

The variable $^O (that's a capital 'O', not a zero) holds the name of the operating system.

Depending on what you want, it may or may not give the answer you want - on my system it gives 'linux' without saying which distro. I'm not so sure about what it says on Windows or MacOS.

Answer (score 3):

A classic one-liner:

```
my $windows=($^O=~/Win/)?1:0;# Are we running on windows?
```

Comment: Except if you're running darwin os !

Comment: Crap!  You're right!  Making it case sensitive seems to fix it.  I've corrected it above. Good catch!

Comment: the case-sensitive version doesn't detect "cygwin"

Answer (score 3):

FYI on Mac computers `$^O` now returns 'darwin' for 10.13.6 (High Sierra), 10.15.4 (Catalina) … and 13.4 (Ventura).

Answer (score 1):

```
#Assign the $home_directory variable the path of the user's home directory
my $home_directory = ($^O eq /Win/) ? $ENV{HOMEPATH} : $ENV{HOME};
#Then you can read/write to files in the home directory
open(FILE, ">$home_directory/my_tmp_file");
print FILE "This is a test\n";
close FILE;
#And/or read the contents of the file
open(FILE, "<$home_directory/my_tmp_file");
while (<FILE>){
    print $_;
}
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic mapping from a CPAN module, check out [`Perl::OSType`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::OSType).

It's used by `Module::Build`.

By "generic mapping," it returns a value from a much smaller set of OS identifiers - in most cases, that's probably more useful (`$^O` can return over 50 values).  Looking at the source, the possible return values are only

```
Unix
Windows
EBCDIC
MacOS
VMS
VOS
RiscOS
Amiga
MPEiX
```

The module has admittedly not been updated for over 5 years, and based on `@brian-d-foy`'s answer, OS2 is notably missing.  Also, if you are looking to use `File::Spec`, his answer is probably better for that use case.

Answer (score -3):

yes using Config module can be a good thing. One more possibility is getting the info from /etc/*release files

for eg..

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="UBUNTU"
VERSION="12.0.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID="UBUNTU"
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.0.2 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Comment: And what about windows?

Comment: @M42 
use Win32;  #module to interact with the win32 API.<br/>
Win32::GetOSName()  - will return the OS name<br/>
Win32::GetOSVersion()<br/>
[CORE] Returns the list (STRING, MAJOR, MINOR, BUILD, ID), where the elements are, respectively: An arbitrary descriptive string, the major version number of the operating system, the minor version number, the build number, and a digit indicating the actual operating system.<br/>You will get such o/p<br/>
<http://s21.postimg.org/ymuhihbsn/win32_os_info_perl.jpg><br/>
for more info abot Win32 module : <br/><http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-0.47/Win32.pm>

Comment: Sure, but there isn't such file as `/etc/os-release` and you don't know in advance on which platform you are.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. It asks: "How can I detect the operating system in Perl?". Your solution doesn't answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I was in edit mode,

Hi @M42, Unix and DOS family have many things different.
for windows, type `msinfo32` on cmd.exe or redirect the o/p to file
`msinfo32 /nfo C:\TEMP\windows_info.nfo`

Comment: @M42, also this will help

`my ( $osvername, $major, $minor, $build, $id ) = Win32::GetOSVersion();`
`print "\n\nOS version - $osvername\nMajor # - $major\nMinor # -  $minor\nBuild - $build\nID -  $id \n\n";`