# How can I detect the operating system in Perl, then conditionally execute commands?

Tags: perl, operating-system, detection

Found this question on "[How can I detect the operating system in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334686/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-perl)" -- but what I need to snippet of Perl that detects the OS, and then uses that value to conditional excute code for OS-A or OS-B; in this case, those being Windows7 and CentOS-5.5.

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course $^O is the definitive answer to this. But you might want to look at [Devel::CheckOS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aCheckOS) which puts a friendly wrapper around it.

Comment: Agree, that's a super user friendly wrapper -- thanks for sharing. Have you given any more though to posting updates to your blog on "Data Munging with Perl"... :-) ...cheers!!

Comment: Oh, I think about it a lot. And then I think "If only I had more spare time" :-/

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec) does it.

[Here.](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SMUELLER/PathTools-3.33/lib/File/Spec.pm)

---

Answer to comment:

I'm not saying to load File::Spec. I'm saying look at how it does its "sub-classing". Really, it's kind of like this:

- Objects do polymorphism.
- Polymorphism is the simplest way to do what you need.
- Create a general pattern of implementation,
- then implement it *for* those platforms you will be using it on.

File::Spec tries to do them all, because it's a CPAN module. But simply look at how it does it, look at how it *folds* platforms into cases. Because it's a core and recommended module, you probably can't go that wrong following the pattern.

*If* your platforms don't fit this pattern, then you are going to have to use additional methods to sniff out the platform. File-system differences might not be the only ones you need to worry about.

I'm not completely 100% happy with the way that FS implements polymorphism, to be exact. But it *is* a strategy. And an example of handling platforms with polymorphism.

Just for discussion: I prefer an extra class. I would base all the FS implementations on an abstract class. On top of that I would subclass that behavior into implementations and *on top of that* I would put one of my favorite patterns Facade/Factory class which is the public face of the class.

Comment: +1 Thanks, looked at the code. Appears that you're saying to load the File::Spec module to do something that just Perl should be able to do alone. Is that correct, or am I missing something? Also, not following in the code were it's providing a conditional logic that I'm able to pass commands to; which is the core of my question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dispatch table like this:

```
my %callback = (
    MSWin32 => sub { win_code() },
    linux   => sub { linux_code() },
);

# run appropriate code
$callback{$^O}->();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, first in case it's not clear, I know nothing about Perl. That said, I did run the code in ptkdb to see what it's doing; appears to be created a hash table that's then used as a lookup. What I don't know is how to transform that code into an "If then" statement. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @blunders try this: `if ($^O =~ /win/i) { windows_code() } else { linux_code() }`

Comment: @blunders, no one has actually said it yet, but `$^O` contains the operating system info, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html for more info