# How to write cross-platform perl code

Tags: perl, cross-platform

A perl script which would include different modules for both Windows and Linux, In order to make it cross-platform, I want someway to implement it, just like in C++:

```
#if _WIN32
//...
#else
//...
#endif
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334686/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-perl

Comment: @Alex I don't see it works: use Win32::Console::ANSI if($^O eq 'MSWin32');

Comment: The loading of modules via `use` is done at compile time.  You can, however, use Module::Load (http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Module-Load-0.20/lib/Module/Load.pm), and say something along the lines of `if($^O eq 'MSWin32'){load 'Win32::Console::ANSI'}else{#do something else...or not...whatever}`

Comment: Just a note: remember to use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) catfile() and catdir() to build file paths and paths in a portable way.

Comment: @Marco De Lellis, I prefer [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class). It's a wrapper around File::Spec that resolves some issues with File::Spec. Note that Windows does support "/" as a directory seperator (natively!), so one can usually get away without using File::Spec or Path::Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[if](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if), [`$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OSNAME):

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', Win32::Console::ANSI::;
```

---

Alternatively,

```
use Win32::Console::ANSI ();
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    require Win32::Console::ANSI;
}
```

so you could also use

```
BEGIN {
    require Win32::Console::ANSI
        if $^O eq 'MSWin32';
}
```

Comment: Can't get the `$^O` link to work. It's http:// perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^O (minus the space)

Comment: I can. :-)  Try linking to the [English](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?English) name.

Comment: @DVK, `use Win32::Console::ANSI ();` is always equivalent to `BEGIN { require Win32::Console::ANSI; }`. It will not call `import` even if it does exist.

Comment: @DVK, It would be different if I had said `use Win32::Console::ANSI;`. By the way, `Module->import` does not throw an error even if `import` does not exist.