# Determine version of Microsoft Windows using perl?

Tags: windows, perl, operating-system, version

I am creating a small perl script on Windows.
I want to determine the version of Windows i.e. XP, Vista, 7, 8, etc.
How can I get this information?
Thank You.

**UPDATE:** *I want to know the Version of Windows on which the script is running!*
Please add some code on how to use the API's as I am a beginner & dont know much about perl.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334686/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-in-perl) one out.

Comment: none of the options from the correct answer give the required information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32;

say Win32::GetOSDisplayName();
say for Win32::GetOSName();
say for Win32::GetOSVersion();
```

If that is not sufficient, you can call [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via [Win32::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::API).

Comment: Thank You @Sinan, that satisfies my needs.

Comment: Does not work for Version > 6.2 ! GetVersionEx is deprecated and the win32-module uses this Windows API too. :-(

Answer (score 2):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

> $^O
>
> The name of the operating system under which this copy of Perl was
> built, as determined during the configuration process. For examples
> see PLATFORMS in perlport.
>
> The value is identical to $Config{'osname'}
> . See also Config and the -V command-line switch documented in
> perlrun.
>
> In Windows platforms, $^O is not very helpful: since it is
> always MSWin32 , it doesn't tell the difference between
> 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/CE/.NET. Use Win32::GetOSName() or
> Win32::GetOSVersion() (see Win32 and perlport) to distinguish between
> the variants.

Comment: I am not asking the platform on which perl was built!
I am asking about the machine on which it is running.

Comment: That is what that is talking about. The variable `$^O` contains that information. However for most versions of Windows it will always return `"MSWin32"`. So for windows you will need to use the functions mentioned above. This has nothing to do with building perl

Comment: can you please show me how to use the functions?
I am getting some error "Undefined subroutine &Win32::GetOSName called"

Comment: I have tried using GetOSVersion() which gives some numbers, dont know what to do with that, according to http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=144660