# Determine version of Microsoft Windows using C Shell Script?

Tags: windows, shell

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189216/determine-version-of-microsoft-windows-using-perl) but that was using perl.
Now my boss tells me I have to use C Shell Script (.csh). I am a beginner & trying to understand things from [here](http://www-cs.canisius.edu/ONLINESTUFF/UNIX/shellprogramming.html). So I created this script:

```
set OS_NAME = (Win32::GetOSVersion());
set major = $OS_NAME[1];
set minor = $OS_NAME[2];
set build = $OS_NAME[3];
set id = $OS_NAME[4];
echo $major;
echo $minor;
echo $build;
echo $id;
```

This is giving me the output:

```
Win32::GetOSVersion
(
)
#blank line
```

How do I get the script to work?
Thank You.

**UPDATE:** Found something [here](https://www.shell-tips.com/2006/11/24/determine-which-windows-os-version-is-running/).
As per the comment that does not work nowadays. So any updated answer for this?

**UPDATE: Found the Solution** [here](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=803).
But its printing the information just like `echo` does.
How do I store that information inside Variables so that I can do some comparison & do my work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cshell, but it looks like `(Win32::GetOSVersion())` is being interpreted as an array, with each parenthesis as a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head banging found the solution:

```
set Ver = `(wmic os get version)`;
echo $Ver;
```

Did not know earlier that the `` operator can catch the output to a variable.
Even a single answer/comment about the same would have saved a lot of my time.

Was hoping for somebody to reply, but despite getting 42 views there was no answer.
Extremely disappointed & let down by the community. :(